# Fonet merging data

Tags: c#, xsl-fo

I have started using fo.net, and the basics seem allright.
I created a simple xsl-fo file and I can generate an pdf

```
FonetDriver driver = FonetDriver.Make();
driver.Render("hello.fo", "hello.pdf");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("hello.pdf");
```

nice and easy. How can I pass datasets into the xsl.fo.

documentation is a bit shoddy, best info I could find is this from their wiki:

> **MontyOnTheRun Dec 10, 2010 at 2:13 PM**    You develop a xslt that merges the xml data and the "layout" in the xsl-fo "template". The end
>   result would then be an xml-fo that can go into this and build the pdf
>   - right?
>
> 1. Load xml data
> 2. Load xsl
> 3. Transform to xsl-fo
> 4. Generate pdf from xsl-fo
> 5. pdf done

but I am a bit stuck on how to follow this.

Comment: Get yourself a good book on XSL FO and learn how to write it. XSL FO can be created from XML source and XSL template as described. Or you can look toward google and see if you can find XSL FO Visual designers out there. Most of these are commercial products.

Comment: thanks kevin. I am cool with that, but I am not 100% sure where it fits in with fo.net. all the demo's i've seen people just to string.replace on tags inside the template. doesn't feel right...

Answer (score 1):

nice tut found here.
this is what i was missing....

[Creating PDF documents from XML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/595650/Creating-PDF-documents-from-XML)